# Tool for monitoring windows processes and folders

Tags: windows, software-rec, monitoring

I am looking for a tool that tracks and keeps information for some processes on windows how long they've been running, when they have had started/closed. Also it would be nice to monitor folders if some data have been added/deleted to them. This is basically what I need. I tried Process Monitor but it gave me too much information. Just for creating a new folder it lists tons of useless information. I just need the time of creation...

I tried and Process Explorer but it doesn't fit my needs either because it shows only the current state of my PC but I need to run some processes for couple of hours and after that to check what went wrong but unfortunately no records are saved.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, but from the description [Watch 4 Folder](http://leelusoft.blogspot.it/2011/10/watch-4-folder-23.html) may be worth trying.

It can monitor files & folders, and both trigger actions and log the activity.